# VMWare Workstation NAT Service crashes after Windows update

Tags: networking, vmware, crash, nat, vmware-workstation

Usual story. Installed Windows updates and then after a reboot all my VMs in VMware Workstation 15 lost network connectivity. I checked and VMWare NAT service was disabled:

[image]

But then if I try to start it, I get error 1067, that it basically crashed:

[image]

Any idea if there's a fix for that?

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 things you can do.

**First:**

Reset the NAT networking in VMware Workstation. Open All Programs and find / run VMware Network Editor.

Once open, click on Change Setting lower right. This resets Network Editor in Admin Mode.

You may wish to Export the VMware Network settings before you start.

[Export Network Settings](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-8563548D-5FD7-4D78-AFAF-4A28E4EA48BD.html)

There is an Export button in the main screen of the Network Editor.

Now, click on NAT in the upper Window and then lower left: Restore Defaults.

Restart the computer and test.

[image: VMware Network Editor]

.

[image: Reset Defaults]

.

See if resetting NAT works - It usually does for me.

**Second:**

If resetting NAT does work, try reinstalling VMware. Uninstall VMware, restart and install again.

Test.

**Third:**

VMware 15 should work, but consider upgrading to VMware V16. That works in the most recent version of Windows 10 Pro and also in Windows 11 Pro

Comment: There's so many settings in my VMs. I would really hate to touch it. Is there any way to restore it without these draconian measures? I mean I didn't expect to touch it. Why is my system f'ed up..... arghhh! MSFT! Never ever will I install those updates!!!!!

Comment: You need to make a note (document) of the settings as that is the only way I know to fix broken NAT.  Yes, I have done this myself.

Comment: I was incorrect. You CAN export the settings and then import them after resetting NAT.   I amended my answer accordingly. Good luck.